# String from an array from an array from the database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay so, first of all, I searched through the www for this question, and I found some question related to arrays but not exactly to mine.

Okay so as you may know, paypal only allows one custom variable to be $POST but I need to gather the product id AND the quantity of the item bought. So to do this I made my custom variable into something that would get the post like (25-1,12-3,13-4) it means, the user bought 3 items(separated by commas), where the first number is the product id (then the separator '-' comes in) and the second one is the quantity. (so they're all in the same row and column)

Now my problem is displaying it from the database. I need to get the product name and details that's why I need to separate the numbers from each array as a string and fetch the data from the database for the information of the product. (I'm using an older version of php anyway, 5.2, I guess.)Now the problem is:

1.) It returns the word 'Array' (literally) so it would say like ArrayArrayArray

2.) How do I explode/separate those data so I can get it because I need the product ID to fetch some other data... I tried exploding it into array, then exploding it again but doesn't work (most likely my code is wrong?)

Here is my code: (I've already connected to the database)

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from transactions") or die(mysql_error()); 
/* My table tag and headers goes here */
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $info['id'] . '</td>';
    echo "<td>";
    $array = $info['product_id_array'];
    $explode_array = explode(",", $array);
    foreach($explode_array as $explode_more){
        $explode_more = explode("-", $explode_array);
        $prod_id = $explode_more[0];
        $quantity = $explode_more[1];
        print_r($prod_id); //should echo the 25 in the array (25-1), right?
        print_r($quantity);
    }

    echo"</td>";
    echo"<tr>";
}
```

If only paypal would allow multiple custom variables T_T Thank you guys. Forgive me if I can't express my question very well or my language is not good, as english is not my first language :), Good day!

Comment: if you print_r($array) before you explode it what does that look like?

Comment: It displays the correct output like 25-1,13-1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable names are mixed up. Inside the foreach-loop, you should do something like this

```
foreach($explode_array as $explode_more){
    $explode_even_more = explode("-", $explode_more);
    $prod_id = $explode_even_more[0];
    $quantity = $explode_even_more[1];
    print_r($prod_id); //should echo the 25 in the array (25-1), right?
    print_r($quantity);
}
```

Note, that `$explode_more` is used inside the loop and `$explore_array` is left as is.

Comment: Wow it worked! I misunderstood the foreach names a bit, I guess. Mister, thank you. I was close, or was I not? Hehe, either way, I really thank you, am happy.

Answer (score 0):

Separate this in multiple tables, never store non-atomic values in 1 column.
Certainly not when they have relation with another table.

Suppose you want to know the sales from a certain product in some period.